# Can I check a condition to raise an error in SQL without using the Exists clause when use for each row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Lets say I have A Table of Articles, and before inserting a new article I would like to check if an article with the same title already exists.

Since I am using the FOR EACH ROW CLAUSE can I treat the conditions, as for each row?

**UPDATE:** This is a question asked in an exam, so i'm not quite sure if it is specified to a specific SQL language, I guess it is more theoretical.
I am just interested if the when condition is valid in this kind of way, without using an Exists clause. Thank you!

The syntax might be inaccurate , but for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NoDuplicateTitles
BEFORE INSERT ON Articles
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.NewspaperId = NewspaperId AND
     NEW.Title = title
RAISE_ERROR;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think it's valid sql in any rdbms.

Comment: if articles may not have the same title then a trigger is not good, Better is to create an unique index on that column

Comment: Yes a unique index is the way to go here.

Comment: thanks I know having a unique primary is the ideal way, but assuming that i am asked to create a trigger, is the when clause valid?

Comment: This is sort of like asking, "I know that a screwdriver is the appropriate tool for putting in this screw but is it ok if I just use this hammer instead?". Use the right tool for the job and there is no question here

Comment: I see that you stated this was asked in a exam. Not sure what DBMS this is for but I would answer that it is not valid because it is the wrong way to handle this situation.